# How to determine if a method is inherited, redefined or new (PHP)

Tags: php, inheritance, methods

I would like a function that checks if a class defines a certain method, similar to `method_exists`, but something like `method_defined($obj, 'method_name');` that would return true if the mentioned method exists AND it is defined in the obj class itself, not inherited. It should return true for new methods not inherited (this would be fine checking if method is defined or not in parent class, something like `method_exists($obj, $method) && !method_exists(get_parent_class($obj), $method)`) and also true for inherited methods that are redefined (don't know how to do it), but return false for inherited methods that are not redefined (don't know either).

Sample code:

```
<?php
class base
{
    var $x = 'x';
    function doit()
    {
        return $this->x;
    }
}

class a extends base
{
    function doit()
    {
        return 'a';
    }
}

class b extends base
{
    var $x = 'b';
}

class c extends base
{
}

function method_defined($obj, $method)
{
    return method_exists($obj, $method); // this is the question
}

function info($obj)
{
    echo get_class($obj) . ": " . $obj->doit();
    echo " " . (int)method_exists($obj, 'doit');
    echo " " . (int)is_subclass_of($obj, 'base');
    echo " " . (int)method_defined($obj, 'doit') . "\n";
}

info(new a); // a a 1 1 1
info(new b); // b b 1 1 0
info(new c); // c x 1 1 0
info(new base); // base x 1 0 1
```

I have seen other similar questions, but they all revert to the Reflection class for this, and I would like to avoid it if at all possible, because it is very heavy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might be surprised at how unheavy Reflection actually is in moderm PHP.... it was heavy 10 years ago, but that's no longer the case

Comment: But if you want to avoid Reflection, look at [get_class_methods()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php), walking the inheritance tree checking against each parent class in turn as necessary... it's likely to be far heavier than Reflection

Comment: `get_class_methods` will only work for newly defined methods, as i mentioned in the problem statement. Won't work to tell inherited from redefined methods. As for Reflection not being heavy, it might end up being the only way, so much better that way...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, this is what I used as a solution.  It uses Reflection, but it is quite simple and effective.

```
function method_defined($ref, $method)
{
    $class = (is_string($ref)) ? $ref : get_class($ref);
    return (method_exists($class, $method)) && ($class === (new \ReflectionMethod($class, $method))->getDeclaringClass()->name);
}
```

Comment: FYI, if a method is defined in a trait, the class name that this code returns is the name of the class that `use`s the trait, not the trait name. Mildly annoying.